# AVAudioRecorder: Speed up playback speed of recording? (Not playback with speed with AVAudioPlayer)

Tags: avfoundation, speech-recognition, avaudiorecorder, avkit, sfspeechrecognizer

I am trying to transcript a long recorded audio file with `SFSpeechRecognizer`. Unfortunately it seems to run in real time, e.g. if the audio file is 1 min long, `SFSpeechRecognizer` will take 1 min to transcript it.

I have not found an option yet to speed it up. I know that `AVAudioPlayer` has an option for speed, but I am wondering if speeding up the recorded file with `AVAudioRecorder` is possible?

Comment: No, it is not possible. There are different speech recognition APIs which process the audio faster.

Comment: Thanks! Which ones would you recommend @NikolayShmyrev?

Comment: Google API is easiest to start probably, its paid though.

Comment: For anyone wondering. Tested it on https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text with an audio file, it is not considerabley faster making a switch worthwhile @NikolayShmyrev

Comment: From my experience it is much faster (LongRunningRecognize), you can probably try with the API, webpage is just for demo.